# How to pass variables through parameters in Java?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and Ive been given a task to write a postage system in Java. Heres my task:

*"Implement a method public booelan updateTrackingHistory(String datetime, String location), which enables the updating of the tracking history for a Parcel as it is being transported from the sender to the recipient, as follows.
If the satchel size has not been set for the Parcel, or if it has already been delivered then the method should immediately return false.
Otherwise the method should construct a new tracking entry noting the date/time and the location, after which the new tracking entry should be appended to the tracking history on a new line.
Once the tracking history has been updated the method should return true, indicating that the tracking update was recorded successfully."*

And this is all my code that I've written so far but I'm a little bit stuck on constructing a new tracking entry and not sure how to continue this method. The last method in this code is where Im stuck.

```
public class parcel {

//Instance Variables
//The info we need to keep track of
private String parcelNumber;
private String senderName;
private String returnAddress;
private String recipientName;
private String deliveryAddress;
private String contactNumber;
private String satchelSize;
private boolean deliveryComplete;
private String trackingHistory;

//Constructors

public parcel (String parcelNumber, String senderName, String returnAddress, String recipientName, 
        String deliveryAddress, String contactNumber, String trackingHistory) {

    this.parcelNumber = parcelNumber;
    this.senderName = senderName;
    this.returnAddress = returnAddress;
    this.recipientName = recipientName;
    this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    this.trackingHistory = "";

}

//Getters
public String getparcelNumber() {

    return parcelNumber;
}

public String getrecipientName() {

    return recipientName;
}

public String getdeliveryAddress() {

    return deliveryAddress;
}

public String getcontactNumber() {

    return contactNumber;
}

//Helper Method.
public int calculatePostageCost() {
    int postCost = 0;
    int trackingFee = 5;

    if(satchelSize.equals("Small") || satchelSize.equals("small")) 
        postCost = trackingFee + 10;

    else if(satchelSize.equals("Medium") || satchelSize.equals("medium"))
        postCost = trackingFee + 13;

    else if(satchelSize.equals("Large") || satchelSize.equals("large"))
        postCost = trackingFee + 17;


    return postCost;
}

//Method
public int selectSatchel(int parcelLength, int parcelWidth) {

    if(satchelSize != null) 
        return -1;

    if(parcelLength > 500 || parcelWidth > 400)

        return 0;

    else {

    //code for finding out smallest parcel size it will fit in  
    return calculatePostageCost();

    }
}

public boolean updateTrackingHistory(String datetime, String location ) {

    if(satchelSize == null || satchelSize.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Check if parcel has already been delivered 
    else if(trackingHistory != null) {

    return false;   

    }


}
```

Comment: In the constructor, instead of `this.trackingHistory = "";` write `this.trackingHistory = trackingHistory`

Comment: next time please less spaces and upper-sized classname and constructor.

Comment: "_I'm a little bit stuck on constructing a new tracking entry and not sure how to continue this method_" ... And what is the question ? Note that your curren method won't compile since you don't return a value in every case.

Answer (score -2):

ok but my main concern is this method here based on the task:

```
public boolean updateTrackingHistory(String datetime, String location ) {

if(satchelSize == null || satchelSize.isEmpty())
{
    return false;
}
//Check if parcel has already been delivered 
else if(trackingHistory != null) {

return false;   

}


}
```

Comment: First of all trackingHistory != null is not going to do much since you initialize the trackingHistory as an empty string in the constructor. You have a boolean field deliveryComplete that would be a good candidate for checking if there has been a delivery. The question remains when and how that is determined. Your problem does not explicitly specify how delivery state is determined. In the updateTrackingHistory you could check if the supplied location equals the deliveryAddress set the deliveryComplete boolean to true.